# using logging operator error connecting from fluentd to elasticsearch

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, fluentd, banzaicloud-logging-operator

Used Banzai logging operator v 4.2.2 which setup fluentbit and Fluentd on k8s v1.25 unable to connect Elasticserach v8.9.0 with below error.

```
The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product.
```

2023-08-16 11:30:37 +0000 [error]: fluent/log.rb:372:error: unexpected error error_class=Elastic::Transport::Transport::Error error="EOFError (EOFError)"
2023-08-16T11:30:37.803235525Z   2023-08-16 11:30:37 +0000 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:1055:main_process: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/elastic-transport-8.2.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/base.rb:324:in `rescue in perform_request' 2023-08-16T11:30:37.803240778Z   2023-08-16 11:30:37 +0000 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:1055:main_process: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/elastic-transport-8.2.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/base.rb:285:in` perform_request'
2023-08-16T11:30:37.803244112Z   2023-08-16 11:30:37 +0000 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:1055:main_process: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/elastic-transport-8.2.1/lib/elastic/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:36:in `perform_request' 2023-08-16T11:30:37.803670295Z   2023-08-16 11:30:37 +0000 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:1055:main_process: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/elastic-transport-8.2.1/lib/elastic/transport/client.rb:176:in` perform_request'
2023-08-16T11:30:37.803685465Z   2023-08-16 11:30:37 +0000 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:1055:main_process: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-8.6.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:71:in `method_missing' 2023-08-16T11:30:37.803689566Z   2023-08-16 11:30:37 +0000 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:1055:main_process: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-8.6.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/info.rb:41:in` info'
2023-08-16 11:30:37 +0000 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:1055:main_process: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-5.3.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:498:in `detect_es_major_version' 2023-08-16T11:30:37.803696370Z   2023-08-16 11:30:37 +0000 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:1055:main_process: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-5.3.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:489:in` block in handle_last_seen_es_major_version'

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the PV creation, PV should be automatically created using gp2/gp3 StorageClass so when the pvc requestd for PV it should create automatically, make sure you have aws-ebs-csi-driver addon configured correctly with proper service account created using below command.

```
aws eks create-addon --cluster-name <EKS cluster name> --addon-name aws-ebs-csi-driver --service-account-role-arn arn:aws:iam::<account-no>:role/<eks cluster name>-cluster-ebs --region "{{REGION}}"
```

and then try to install ECK.